# My solution in JavaScript for the kata kyu 5 City Swim - 2D passes the tests but not the attempts

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm trying to solve this kyu 5 kata:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/58e77c88fd2d893a77000102/

My solution passes the tests but not the attemps, and I cant figure out why. This is my code:

```
    function rainVolume(towers) {
        let res = 0;
        return (function f(){
            if(towers.length>=3){
                let greatestIndex = towers.indexOf(Math.max(...towers));
                towers[greatestIndex] = -1;
                let secondIndex = towers.indexOf(second = Math.max(...towers));
                towers.splice(greatestIndex,1);
                //towers.splice(secondIndex,1)
                let between = (x=greatestIndex-secondIndex)<0 ? towers.splice(greatestIndex,x=Math.abs(x)-1) : towers.splice(secondIndex+1,x);
                res += second*between.length-between.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                f(towers);
            }
            return res
        })();
    }
```

Basicly I thought that if I took the positions of the largest tower and the second largest in the array (`greatestIndex` and `secondIndex`), then multiply the second largest tower's high by the number of towers that are between `greatestIndex` and `secondIndex`, I could get the rain volume between those positions by substracting the sum of highs of the towers that are in between.

My english is poor and I dont know If I explained it right

Answer (score 0):

Got it by adding `-1` to `x` on `towers.splice(secondIndex+1,x)`